# DRF Image serializer with nested thumnails

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, response

I'm writing django project, in which I have the following models in my media_app application:

```py
class Image(File):
    """
    Image model class, through which client will get images stored on AWS S3.
    """
    # ... (not needed in serializer fields)



class Thumbnail(File):
    """
    Related model for Image, that contains thumbnails of Image.
    """
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        Image,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='thumbnails',
    )
    resolution = models.CharField(
        _('resolution'),
        max_length=11,
        validators=[resolution_validator],
    )
    
    # ...
```

File class is base model class for media files in my project. It contains `mime_type, origina_file_name, size`, etc.

My question is how can I write serializer for Image, that will have the following structure:

```json
{
  "2775f83e-1608-4135-91d3-f357484df3b1": {
    "full_size": "http://localhost:8000/api/media/2775f83e-1608-4135-91d3-f357484df3b1/",
    "358x227": "http://localhost:8000/api/media/8809a43d-c387-4a8e-9c84-8419c406ecd8/",
    "190x121": "http://localhost:8000/api/media/cb32967e-a576-44ee-b636-6e3a65ec93ba/"
  }
}
```

Where `"2775f...df3b1"` is pk of Image, `"full_size"` its own get url (model has method/property `api_url`, that generate endpoint url to media file get view) and other fields (`"358x227"` and `"190x121"`) are urls of related thumbnails (keys are from resolution fields in Thumbnail). This structure is not common for DRF, so I've not found the solution in documentation...

Serializer will be used in other ModelSerializers. Image contains foreignkeys to other models, those need media files (I'm not using Django Content Type, just nullable OneToOnes), and in api_url there is will be normal ModelSerializer for Image, so I need above structure only in related models like Article.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked some other stackOverflow questions, and find `.to_representation` method of ModelSerializer. To get needed representation (above structure), and I just rewrote this method. The result is in following code:

```py
class RelatedImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        thumbnails = instance.thumbnails.all()
        image_api_urls = {"full_size": instance.api_url}
        for thumbnail in thumbnails:
            image_api_urls[thumbnail.resolution] = thumbnail.api_url
        
        
        return {str(instance.pk): image_api_urls}
    
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('id',) # will not be used, because to_representation method was overwrite
```

All works fine, but I've not checked all cases, just 2 endpoints of my API.